# I want to convert this into a javascript function OR convert image to blue or yellow via css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code.

```
<svg class="defs-only">
  <filter id="monochrome" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
          x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="0.00 0 0 0  0 
              0.00 0 0 0  0  
              1 0 0 0  0 
                0  0 0 1  0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
<a class="profile-link" href="#" title="More about Amelia Bellamy-Royds">
  <img class="profile-pic" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/91525/AmeliaBR-bw.jpg"/></a>
<a class="profile-link" href="#" title="More about AmeliaBR">
  <img class="profile-pic" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/91525/AmeliaBR2-bw.jpg"/></a>
```

CSS

```
.profile-link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  max-width: 80%;
}
.profile-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: #222 0.2em 0.2em 1em;
  /*
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}
.profile-link:hover .profile-pic, 
.profile-link:focus .profile-pic {
  */
  -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
  filter:  url(#monochrome);
  box-shadow: #224 0.2em 0.2em 0.6em 0.1em;
}
.defs-only {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0; width: 0;
  overflow: none;
  left: -100%;
}
```

What this does is that it displays a filtered image on the screen. i want to convert it into a function. The file should be uploaded by the use and then when I click on a button this filter should be applied. What should I do? This is what i have done so far.

HTML

```
<form>
    <input id="file-input" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
</form>
<svg class="defs-only">
  <filter id="monochrome" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
          x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="1.00 0 0 0  0 
              1.00 0 0 0  0  
              1 0 0 0  0 
                0  0 0 1  0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
<a class="profile-link" href="#" title="More about Amelia Bellamy-Royds">
<pre id="output"></pre>
</a>

     <script>
            var input = document.getElementById("file-input");
            input.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
                var file = input.files[0],
                    img = new Image(),
                    reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.width = 300;
                    img.src = event.target.result;
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }, false);
        </script>


<body>  
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.profile-link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  max-width: 80%;
}
.profile-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: #222 0.2em 0.2em 1em;
  /*
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}
.profile-link:hover .profile-pic, 
.profile-link:focus .profile-pic {
  */
  -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
  filter:  url(#monochrome);
  box-shadow: #224 0.2em 0.2em 0.6em 0.1em;
}
.defs-only {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0; width: 0;
  overflow: none;
  left: -100%;
}
```

Comment: Both CSS's in your question are exactly the same, why include it twice? And you haven't clearly stated your question: "What should I do? This is what i have done so far.". See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (in your code only the button is inside the html body?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the image in an html page you can apply the filter by adding the filter class to the image:

```
var image = document.getElementById("uploaded-image");
image.className += "profile-pic";
```